# Use the plus sign "+" instead of dash "-" in URLs

Tags: url-rewriting

Is it possible to use the plus sign instead of the dash as the word delimiter in the url? And if so, how exactly would that be done?

e.g.: `www.example.com/some-title/` becomes `www.example.com/some+title/`

Of course, ideally it would have to work with posts, pages and custom posts.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want this done? It doesn't seem like it would have many benefits and it would be a fairly complicated change to make.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Jaquith uses "+" as the search query string delimiter in his Nice Search Plugin. H[ere's what he does](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/nice-search/tags/0.3/nice-search.php):

```
function cws_nice_search_redirect() {
    if ( is_search() && strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/' ) === false && strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/search/' ) === false ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/search/' . str_replace( array( ' ', '%20' ),  array( '+', '+' ), get_query_var( 's' ) ) ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Perhaps it may be of some use for reference?

Comment: Yeah, but `+` changes to a space when it's run through `urldecode()`, which WP does when matching against rewrite rules. You'd need to make sure you're checking against the correct slug in `WP_Query`, as well as modifying the permalink output, and maybe even filtering on `redirect_canonical`.

Comment: Doesn't Mark's code run *after* URL rewrites are applied? (mod_rewrite is all still a bit of a mystery to me)

Comment: Yes, but spaces in searches are ok. If you have a space in the slug you look up, it won't match what's in the database.

Comment: Sorry, to answer your question, I don't know when his code runs, but it redirects the page request to use the plus signs, so you get a fresh load starting with plus signs.

Answer (score 0):

## DONT USE `.HTACCESS` for that!

Its madness, WP will generate links with `-` and your site will be in evergreen looping by `.htaccess`... Instead, you need to modify url generation code:

Insert this in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sample-permalink', 'MyajaxSamplePermalink',1);
function MyajaxSamplePermalink($data) {
    // check that we're dealing with a product, and editing the slug
    $post_id = isset($_POST['post_id']) ? intval($_POST['post_id']) : 0;
    $new_title = isset($_POST['new_title'])? $_POST['new_title'] : null;
    $post_name = isset($_POST['new_slug'])? $_POST['new_slug'] : $new_title;
    //on first fire, there is not set the "new_slug"
    $_POST['new_slug'] = ISSET($_POST['new_slug']) ? $_POST['new_slug'] : slug_modify($post_name); 
}
//disable slug beforehand Post Update  action (also, in navigation menus and etc...)
add_filter('name_save_pre', 'MyfilterNameSavePre');
function MyfilterNameSavePre($post_name) { 
    if (!empty($_POST['post_ID']) || !empty($_POST['post_name']) || !empty($_POST['post_title']) ){
        // check that we're dealing with a product, and editing the slug
        $post_id = !empty($_POST['post_ID']) ? intval($_POST['post_ID']) : 0;
        $new_slug = !empty($_POST['post_name']) ? $_POST['post_name'] :  $_POST['post_title'];
        //if got from new post
        if ($post_id && !empty($_POST['_wp_http_referer']) ) {  if (stripos($_POST['_wp_http_referer'],'wp-admin/post-new.php')!==false) { $post_name = slug_modify($new_slug); $_POST['post_name']=$post_name;} } 
    }
    return $post_name;
}
//disable slug on any update
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'myappend_slug', 3); function myappend_slug($dataaaaaa) { 
    if (!empty($_POST['_wp_http_referer'])) {
        if (stripos($_POST['_wp_http_referer'],'wp-admin/post-new.php')!==false) {
            $dataaaaaa['post_name']=slug_modify(     (!empty($_POST['post_name']) ? $_POST['post_name'] :$dataaaaaa['post_title'])      );
        } 
    }
    return $dataaaaaa; 
}
function slug_modify($slg) {return str_replace('-','+',$slg);}
```