# Using plus (+) sign instead of space (-) in WordPress URL

Tags: url-rewriting

How to change space (-) sign to plus (+) sign in clean URL WordPress?

Like:

`http://www.whitelotuscorporation.co.in/anax_wp/about-us/`

to:

`http://www.whitelotuscorporation.co.in/anax_wp/about+us/`

You can see where the change need to be done— `about+us` instead of `about-us` in the URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use the plus sign "+" instead of dash "-" in URLs](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14586/use-the-plus-sign-instead-of-dash-in-urls)

Comment: I don't think this a duplicate but the suggested duplicate is worth reading. That dash is pretty heavily embedded into WordPress. I worked out a way to alter the permalink but I am getting a lot of 404s when I do. Why do you need this? Why is it necessary?

Comment: I've moved my answer to this older duplicate topic: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14586/use-the-plus-sign-instead-of-dash-in-urls

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible without modifying a core file. The function WordPress uses for this is called `sanitize_title_with_dashes` You can find it in wp-includes/formatting.php on

It doesn't offer any filters, so you will need to make a change to this line:

```
$title = str_replace( array( '%c2%a0', '%e2%80%93', '%e2%80%94' ), '-', $title );
```

I wouldn't recommend modifying core WordPress files at all, so if you do this, be sure to try it out on a test site before implementing it - and even then make sure you have everything backed up.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `.htaccess` file in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tags that were created by WordPress:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)$ $1+$2 [R=301]
```

This has been tested and verified using the [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).

Comment: `HTACCESS` method is DISASTER in this case! instead, url-generation needs to be changed!